# How to add outer glow (box shadow?) properly on button

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I add this outer glow shadow to this button on Flutter?

[image]

On Figma:

It's done by either

```
filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 85, 85, 0.7));
```

or

```
Effect: Drop Shadow
Radius: 20px
Offset: 0px, 0px
rgba(255, 85, 85, 0.7)
```

Applying a `BoxShadow` to the container which contains the button does not work:

```
BoxShadow(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, _opacity),
            offset: Offset(_xOffset, _yOffset),
            blurRadius: _blurRadius,
            spreadRadius: _spreadRadius,
```

Because it's constrained by the container size.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `blurRadius` and if you want to make color more visible add `spreadRadius` value.

```
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.red,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.red,
        blurRadius: 30,
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap button with the container and give it box-shadow property.
it works...

```
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(18.0),
          ),
          color: Colors.red,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.pink,
              spreadRadius: 4,
              blurRadius: 10,
              offset: Offset(0, 0),
            )
          ]),
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed:(){},
        child: Text("submit"),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```